# Can I use LINQ with .net Framework version 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Can anyone tell me if I will be able to use LINQ after upgrading from 4.0 to 4.5?

My project currently targets the 4.0 Framework. I need to upgrade to version 4.5 or later to be able to use the Braintree payment processing api.  I've had problems in the past after an upgrade, though they may have been after upgrading from 3.5.

Comment: Create a new project, point it to 4.5, and see for yourself if you can use LINQ in that project.

Comment: If you find your question closed will be because they encourage the site to be used for specific code related questions. When you have something this general as your question, you could try forums or Quora.

Comment: Understand. Thanks for the info. IDK, seems a little harsh but I'll get over it. To the anointed here it probably seems like a mundane question, but it's been a while since I upgraded a project and the last time I did the core changes to the .net framework between 3 and 4 killed a LOT of work that I didn't anticipate. I didn't want to go through that again... but I guess I'll go read community guidelines and make sure to stay between the ditches from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  yes.

you can easily test this yourself.  here is how I would do it (based on the suggestion by Servy in the comments below your post).

1. create a simple project in 4.0
2. create an object collection (eg. of type `IList<string>` ) and populate it with some sample data
3. use some linq to query that object collection
4. Make sure it compiles
5. upgrade the project to 4.5
6. Test
7. ???
8. Profit